# How can I update my news feed after I add new post

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express, typeorm

I have a `react` frontend app with `nodejs/express` and `typeorm/mysql` on the backend. I have built a clone of twitter's "news feed" where we can post a new tweet(article). At the top, I have an input field where user can submit new post. Once the user submits new post, he has to refresh the page in order to be able to see new post. How can I achieve 'live reload' without reloading the app or seeing the new post once it is submitted. I am using `useEffect()` hook and `fetch` to send HTTP requests to communicate with backend.

Code for fetching posts and creating new one from the homepage:

```
const [posts, setPosts] = React.useState([]);
const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = React.useState(false);
const [error, setError] = React.useState(null);
const [post, setNewPost] = React.useState("");


 React.useEffect(() => {
  fetch(`${serverUrl()}/posts`)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then(
    (posts) => {
      setIsLoaded(true);
      setPosts(posts);
    },
    (error) => {
      setIsLoaded(true);
      setError(error);
    }
  );
 }, []);

  const createNewPost = async (postData) => {
    return fetch(`${serverUrl()}/posts`, {
      method: "POST",
      // add new
      headers: { "Content-type": "application/json", userid: token },
      body: JSON.stringify(postData),
    }).then((data) => {
      return data.json();
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   await createNewPost({ title: "Lorem ipsum", body: post });
   setNewPost("");
 };
```

Comment: Can you share your code? Especially the part where you store all your blog posts.

Comment: @Keimeno I'm currently storing in in component's state. Just added state and hooks/methods for fetching and creating posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `createNewPost` method, after the post has been added successfully, you must push the new post to your state.

```
const createNewPost = async (postData) => {
    return fetch(`${serverUrl()}/posts`, {
      method: "POST",
      // add new
      headers: { "Content-type": "application/json", userid: token },
      body: JSON.stringify(postData),
    }).then((data) => {
      // success!
      setPosts([...posts, postData]);
      return data.json();
    });
  };
```

But of course, `postData` must match the schema of a single post inside your `posts` array for this to work.
The best solution for this is, to have the backend return the new post as JSON object, and then update the `posts` array.

Comment: Thank you! It should update the state to cause the "refresh" of the page.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround would be that you could just manipulate the state of your "posts" variable.
In your createNewPost, if the promise returns in success without any errors or exceptions, i.e. enters into "then" block, you can append your new post -> {title: "new post", body: post} to the already fetched "posts" variable. This way state will be updated and you will see the new post.

i.e.

```
let prevPosts = [...posts];
prevPosts.push(newPost);
setPosts(prevPosts); // Append at last. You can even push at first index, that way post will appear at top.
```

So even if you refresh, the new posts will be loaded, as you already did a create query at backend while submitting the post and later updated the post variable.